# How to create buffer around numpy array for specified rectangle

Tags: python, numpy

I have this problem, when I have two numpy arrays a and b, where b is same as a but with just some data modification. For easy explanation, here is minimum working simplified example.

My goal is to create a buffer around the rectangle - defined by xmin, xmax, ymin, xmax - where the values would be result of weights. So in this example value of first pixel around rectangle is 75% from array b and 25% from array a and so on..

I managed to create this dirtiest example that is working, but its really ugly and non extendable if I want to use wider buffer, for example 5 pixels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create array a filled with number 10
a = np.full((20,20),10)

# create array b filled with number 20
b = np.full((20,20),20)

# central aprt of array b
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = 5, 5, 15, 15
b[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] = 10
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.imshow(b)

def blend_edges(data_background, data_forwground, weights, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):

    a = data_background
    b = data_forwground

    for distance, w in enumerate(weights, start=1):
        # on edges
        b[ymin:ymax, xmin-distance,] = (b[ymin:ymax, xmin-distance,] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin:ymax, xmin-distance,] * (w))
        b[ymin:ymax, xmax-1+distance,] = (b[ymin:ymax, xmax-1+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin:ymax, xmax-1+distance] * (w))
        b[ymin-distance, xmin:xmax,] = (b[ymin-distance, xmin:xmax,] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance, xmin:xmax,] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance, xmin:xmax,] = (b[ymax-1+distance, xmin:xmax,] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance, xmin:xmax,] * (w))

        # diagonal
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance,] = (b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymin-1-distance:ymin-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-1-distance:ymin-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))

    for distance, w in enumerate(weights[1:], start=2):
        # ul
        b[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance,] = (b[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance,] = (b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance] * (w))
        # br
        b[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] * (w))
        # ur
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] = (b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-2+distance:xmax-1+distance] * (w))
        b[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin+1-distance:ymin+2-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        # bl
        b[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] = (b[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-2+distance:ymax-1+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+1-distance:xmin+2-distance] * (w))

    for distance, w in enumerate(weights[2:], start=3):
        # ul
        b[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance,] = (b[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance,] = (b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance] * (w))
        # br
        b[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] * (w))
        # # ur
        b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] = (b[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin-distance:ymin+1-distance, xmax-3+distance:xmax-2+distance] * (w))
        b[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] = (b[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymin+2-distance:ymin+3-distance, xmax-1+distance:xmax+distance] * (w))
        # # bl
        b[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] = (b[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-3+distance:ymax-2+distance, xmin-distance:xmin+1-distance] * (w))
        b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance] = (b[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance] * (1.-w)) + (a[ymax-1+distance:ymax+distance, xmin+2-distance:xmin+3-distance] * (w))

    return b

weights = [0.75,0.5,0.25]

blend_edges(a,b,weights,xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax )


ax2.imshow(b)
plt.show()
```

Result of the code above:
[image]

Comment: Does this have to work for arbitrary arrays, or are the arrays constant (or at least one of them)?

Comment: @AxelDonath in my case arrays are always constant

Answer (score 0):

I think this the closest to what you would like to achieve:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.full((20, 20), 10)

b = np.full((20, 20), 20)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = 5, 5, 15, 15
b[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] = 10


def blend_edges_general(a, b, weights, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    """Blend edges of two arrays."""
    w = np.ones((ymax - ymin, xmax - xmin))

    for value in weights:
        w = np.pad(w, 1, mode="constant", constant_values=value)

    width = len(weights)

    weights = np.zeros(a.shape)
    weights[ymin - width: ymax + width, xmin - width: xmax + width] = w
    
    return (weights * a) + (1 - weights) * b

result = blend_edges_general(a, b, [0.75, 0.5, 0.25], xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

axes[0].imshow(b)
axes[1].imshow(result)
```

Which gives:

[image]

The key idea here was to rely on `np.pad` to iteratively create a boundary around the rectangle with the requested weight. This should generalize to arbitrary weights. However I noticed that my code does not give the exact same result as yours. The values differ by 0.5 for the most outer and most inner "rectangular ring", so you might want to double check both implementations.